# Kotlin Coroutines choosing Dispatcher

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to figure out which Dispatcher to use in what case.

I read some documentation and came up with this:

- Default → CPU work
- Main → main (update UI)
- Unconfined
- IO → writing file / network tasks

Is this right?

What about Unconfined?

Comment: In production code you'll normally never use `Unconfined`. It's a special-purpose no-op dispatcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right in your assumptions about the dispatcher types. Unconfined dispatcher –

> A coroutine dispatcher that is not confined to any specific thread
>
> Unconfined dispatcher is appropriate when coroutine does not consume CPU time nor updates any shared data (like UI) that is confined to a specific thread.

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher) and [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html)